# Microsoft Project Server 2013 Site error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to connect to my site created in Project Server 2013 but getting following error.

**Event Viewer log**

[image]

**Web Site Error Message**

[image]

What is the fix here?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to do the following:**

- Go to Services > Search For SharePoint Timer Service > Make sure that it's started and try to restart it. then reset IIS
- Again, find all related Project server services and make sure it was started.

> If the issue is not solved, try to check the correlation ID  using [**ULS Viewer**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/uls-viewer-tool/) and come back with its details.